# System.InvalidOperationException contains authorization metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports authorization

Tags: asp.net, amazon-cognito

I' m trying to add authentication to the routes of the REST API, y had configured the AWS Cognito in mi `.net` app in `Startup.cs` and in `appsettings.js`, but when I try to GET the response of an authenticated route of the API, I am having this error in the console.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoint AOSP.Controllers.LeadsController.GetLead (AOSP) contains authorization metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports authorization.
```

I had added `app.UseAuthentication();` in the configuration of `Startup.cs`

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();
            ...
        }
```